Can I put a 20 amp plug on a 20 amp outlet wired to a 30 amp / 220v circuit breaker line?
In our house (Asia) we have 3 bedrooms with each having a dedicated outlet for AC
and each having their own lines to connected to their own 30 amp / 240v circuit breakers. All outlets are rated 20 amps only and not 30 which I find confusing.
For the two bedrooms, we use 0.75HP AC 240v each and one 1.5HP for the third room.
If I do a bit of math, I would think that a 0.75 HP AC is around 550 watts and a 30 amp circuit breaker 240v can take 7200 watts which I would think is more than enough for the AC. As for the outlet which is rated 20 amp 240v should be able to handle 4400 watts.
My question is, I would like to put a smart plug rated 20amps or maybe even 16amps 240v to each of the outlets of the 0.75HP ACs only. Is it safe?
EDIT: Changed voltage from 220 to 240.

Are you in the US? A 30 amp breaker on a 220v line is 6600 watts but then gets derated at 80% to 5280. The 20 amp gets derated to 3520.

Asia. Sorry my bad. It should be 240v. Recalculating degradation would mean 30amps would be 5760 watts and 20 amps would be 3840 watts. 3600 watts for 16 amps degraded to 2880. Should still be enough though right?

The breaker will not protect the 20 Amp device, it will not trigger till 30 amps are exceeded

'Asia' is not a country. This will be specific to the local electrical code. It's critical that the cable is sized for 30A (unlikely) but the local code quite possibly allows placing smaller sockets on higher-rated circuits.

If you do, there are plugs/receptacles with fuses/breakers built in that would be a bit safer.  I think these fuses are more common in Europe.

Even if country's electrical code allows it, I would not consider it safe to have an outlet rated for 20A on a circuit with a 30A breaker.
The primary function of a breaker is to protect the wires, outlets and other items connected to the circuit from overheating and causing a fire if too much current runs through them.
An outlet that is designed for 20A will handle a current of 20A without dangerous warming, but if you pass more current through it then all bets are off. If such an outlet is used on a circuit with a 30A breaker, then there are conditions where too much current passes through the outlet, but it is still within the limits of the breaker.
What I would advise you to do is:

Double check the specifications for your ACs with regard to how much current they draw, or how much electrical power they use.
If the current draw is below 20A, replace those 30A breakers with 20A (or lower) versions. Then you can use sockets and smart plugs rated for 20A.
If the current draw is above 20A, replace your sockets with new ones that are designed to handle 30A. You then also may need to take a hard look at the plug of the AC if it can handle the current needs.


This answer needs to be improved.  Asking a homeowner to disregard the electrical code is not good advice.  I also think a complete answer needs to consider the possibility of 2 or more circuit breakers between the main disconnect and the appliance.

What?  You can have an outlet rated lower than the breaker, as long as the wiring meets the minimum for the breaker (e.g. 15A outlet, 12ga wire, on 20A breaker).  You can't have an outlet rated higher than the breaker (e.g. 20A outlet on 15A breaker).

@Huesmann 15A outlets are actually special in that they must be designed to handle 20A. That's why 15A outlets are allowed on a 20A circuit.
